# Log date and external ip address with curl and batch (Windows)

Tags: windows, ip, batch-file, logging, curl

I am having weird issues where my external IP is changed VERY often as in every 2, 3 minutes.

I have a dynamic dns service in place that I update via task scheduler with curl called in a batch file.

I'm in the process of debugging that and to do so I'd need to log(append) the date and time and each response from CURL to a file.

I am able to echo to a file, but have no clue how to append date/time and curl response.

The environment is ws2012.

Thanks in advance!
Here's the snippet I have in at the moment

```
curl -k http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?xdfSDASDQW232FFD
ECHO I ran! I really did! >c:\TestBat.log
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your current script?

Comment: added it at the top!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch solution, appends to log file. Change `>>` to `>` to overwrite:

```
@echo off
set logfile=.\curl.log

echo [ %date% %time% ]>>%logfile%
curl -s -k http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?xdfSDASDQW232FFD>>%logfile%
```

Comment: it should write the curl response too, but thanks

Comment: @grumpygamer Can be done, see update.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend skipping curl all together and using Powershell instead since that is native WS technology and can be used to send a HTTP POST as well.  Here's a simple two-liner that logs your external IP and the current time to the file C:\temp\debuglog.txt:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://icanhazip.com -Method get
"{0};{1}" -f $response.content.trim(), (get-date -format u) | out-file -filepath 'C:\temp\debuglog.txt' -append
```

Put this in a file that ends in .ps1 and run it via task scheduler:

```
Program: powershell
Arguments: -executionpolicy bypass C:\temp\debugscript.ps1
```

Comment: This is awesome but it should also update the DNS at afraid.org; maybe this should be

`$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?xdfSDASDQW232FFD -Method get
"{0};{1}" -f $response.content.trim(), (get-date -format u) | out-file -filepath 'C:\temp\debuglog.txt' -append`

Comment: Yes, I believe I posted this before you had added your command to your question :-) Feel free to accept beatcracker's or my answer if you think that solves your problem.